Found conflicts between different versions that could not be resolved
Visual Studio Professional 2022 is reporting this error:
Found conflicts between different versions of "Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity" that could not be resolved.

There was a conflict between "Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity, Version=1.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc96fa93a217f7a1" and "Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc96fa93a217f7a1".

    "Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity, Version=1.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc96fa93a217f7a1" was chosen because it was primary and "Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc96fa93a217f7a1" was not.

    References which depend on "Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity, Version=1.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc96fa93a217f7a1" [C:\Users\will\.nuget\packages\kent.boogaart.helpertrinity\1.5.2\lib\net45\Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity.dll].
        C:\Users\will\.nuget\packages\kent.boogaart.helpertrinity\1.5.2\lib\net45\Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity.dll
          
    Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\will\.nuget\packages\kent.boogaart.helpertrinity\1.5.2\lib\net45\Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity.dll".
            C:\Users\will\.nuget\packages\kent.boogaart.helpertrinity\1.5.2\lib\net45\Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity.dll
    
    References which depend on or have been unified to "Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc96fa93a217f7a1" [].
        C:\Users\will\.nuget\packages\kent.boogaart.converters\1.3.1\lib\net45\Kent.Boogaart.Converters.dll
          

    Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\will\.nuget\packages\kent.boogaart.converters\1.3.1\lib\net45\Kent.Boogaart.Converters.dll".
            C:\Users\will\.nuget\packages\kent.boogaart.converters\1.3.1\lib\net45\Kent.Boogaart.Converters.dll STBA    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    2401        

My project only references Kent.Boogaart.Converters (1.3.1). When I install this, it automatically downloads Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity (1.5.2). This is the only version of this library contained in my packages folder:

If I check the transitive packages for the project it is (as expected) picking 1.5.2:

I have tried:

Uninstall package, clean build, rebuild, reinstall package
Delete .nuget/packages folder, clean build, rebuild, restore packages
Delete .vs folder, clean build, rebuild, restore packages

I'm completely baffled as to what this conflict is or where it's coming from. None of these packages have been updated for years (this is an old project) and I'm pretty sure this wasn't happening before.
Any ideas?

Hi, it seems a MSB3277 error, did you try to follow this doc  to troubleshoot your issue?

From looking at the error message, it seems a MSB3277. For this issue, here are suggestions you can check:
1.If you use  PackageReference, please check if you have referenced "Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity, Version=2.0.5.0 in .csproj file. If you use packages.config, please check it in packages.config file of your root project.
2.Please try to use Update-Package Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity -reinstall from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio to update Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity to the latest version.
3.It seems there is still that higher version(2.0.5) of "Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity in the cache, or in a project, or in a reference item. Please try to clear nuget cache.Besides try to  search this package (HelperTrinity) globally and see if a higher version will be found.
4.If you are using the .NET Framework, please try to use Binding redirects
<assemblyIdentity name="Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity"
    publicKeyToken="xxx"
    culture="en-us" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.5.0" newVersion="1.5.2.0" />

5.It seems the package is a third-party package. I noticed from nuget website,

The owner has unlisted Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity package. This could mean that the package is deprecated, has security vulnerabilities or shouldn't be used anymore.

Since Kent.Boogaart.Converters depends on Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity and the owner has unlisted Kent.Boogaart.HelperTrinity package, are you able to use Kent.Boogaart.Converters normally? If not, please contact the owner for detailed information.
